# Zend_Auth_Storage_Session serializes object attributes

Tags: session, serialization, storage, authentication, zend-framework

I am storing User object in Zend_Auth_Storage_Session as a array element on valid authentication.

```
 $authSession = new Zend_Auth_Storage_Session();
 $authSession->write(array('user' => $user));
```

When I read Zend_Auth_Storage_Session, users lastLogin property, which is DateTime instance on session write, is string.

Comment: Am not clear as to what your asking.

Comment: Sorry. I got object of custom type User. One of its properties is 'lastLogin' which is of type DateTime (php api). I write user to Zend_Auth_Storage_Session. When i read user from session, 'lastLogin' is string representation of DateTime objec. I presume it's because of serialization. What I would like to know is how to go around it without having to instantiate new DateTime each time I read user from session.

Comment: After reading from storage, what does the 'lastLogin' string value look like?

Comment: @Tobi It's a string representation of the DateTime object that was written, e.g. '2011-12-04 03:14:32'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cbaby, Am not saying this is the solution but its working fine for me because I can access the 'lastLogin' normally. Maybe something else wrong somewhere. Ensure that your setting the date correctly.

```
$user = new stdClass();
$user->name = 'Mary';
$user->lastLogin= new DateTime(); 

$authSession = new Zend_Auth_Storage_Session();
$authSession->write(array('user' => $user));

$read = $authSession->read();
echo $read['user']->lastLogin->format('Y-m-d');
echo '<br>' . $read['user']->lastLogin->getTimezone()->getName();
```

Comment: The problem was in updating user's loginTime after it gets written to session so I can store new value in db. Didn't know that I could update object already written to session by its reference.